# Showing a dialog will call which activity lifecycle function?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have created a simple dialog using -

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Myactivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
dialog.show();
```

When I show and dismiss this dialog, I want to update a textView in `MyActivity`. So I have put something in `onResume()` assuming it gets called when you dismiss a `dialog`. 
Is it true? or do we have any other way of updating this `textView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update your `TextView` implementing  [OnDismissListener interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html):

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            //update your textView
    }
});
```

Comment: This answers my question 'the other way of doing it'. Would like it if somebody answers my first question as well.

Comment: And what is exactly your first question?

Comment: Android documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause() says if any activity is covered by another activity yet still visible, `onPause()` will be called. But showing this `Dialog` is not calling `onPause()` so may be I am misinterpreting the theory. I want to clarify this only.

Comment: Showing a dialog doesn't implied that the Activity goes to the background. It seems to me more like when you set a view over another view.